# Java implementation of common unix file utilities like ls, cat, etc

Tags: java, unix

A similar question exists but the best answer seems to state there is no pure solution, but rather one needs to call the operating system.

Why am i after such utilities, primarily so i can integrate them into the groovy shell.

Comment: *"A similar question exists"* Link to the question.

Comment: @mP, you have almost 100 questions without an accepted answer! That must be a some sort of record. ;)

Comment: perfect opportunity to write such a library, if it really doesn't exist... ;-)

Comment: @mP so if you'll decide to write it, let us know when it'll be done... :-)

Answer (score 4):

Some (mostly text-processing related) unix commands are implemented here: http://www.unix4j.org

Answer (score 0):

I am unaware of a pre-cooked, drop in jar, and [this same question on superuser](https://superuser.com/questions/282530/cross-platform-implementation-of-gnu-tools-preferably-java) indicates there isnt one.  However, libraries such as:

- http://commons.apache.org/lang/
- http://commons.apache.org/io/
- http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/

Should make life easier to implement them.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5666514/command-shell-for-a-mobile-phone) also mentions a solution for ls

Comment: How does guava compare unix file utilities like ls (list) i dont see the similarities at all... ls takes parameters and prints a listing...sure it can be done with guava or even plain java but your answers are no way near or complete solutions as a replacement for the unix utils done in pure java.

Comment: @mP: as I said in the answer, I am unaware of a java replacement for the unix utils and I very much doubt there is one.  See also the superuser question I linked to.   The libraries listed provide some additional abstractions above standard Java so they will make life a little easier for implementing things like ls, cat, etc.  However they are not a drop in replacement. You will have to roll your own as far as Im aware.

Comment: @DG yes guava no - this is not a problem that is about ioc or di, commons-io yes its a start if one was to write your own. The super -user q doesnt really say much.

Answer (score -1):

Most of this functionality is available in Java, it just has different names.

If you want to call these applications you can use Runtime.exec();

Comment: Thats not a pure java solution.

Comment: The reason i have so many unaswered questions i because i dont get answers. Read my q and browse the answers and see how poor they are.

Comment: I mean if im on windows, i probably dont have "ls" so your answer is not really a proper solution nor is it portable.

Comment: Java has a way of doing what you want already.  You say you want a pure Java solution, but you want to use Unix like commands to do it. Can you see why we are confused as to what you want? It appears what you want it program in Java using only your knowledge of shells commands??

Comment: Mate with answers like this, one can say just program it, java is turing complete its just a matter of writing whatever from scratch. Thats not a real answer It may be the only answer but in te spirit of leveeraging the work of others (which is what my q states) this in no way helps.

Comment: Telling me there are no libraries available may be true but pointing me at Runtime.exec or ProcessBuilder and the like is well wrong.

Comment: I am not suggesting some academic exercise, Java has basic libraries to do exactly the same things. They are core libraries you will find covered in the Java tutorials. These functions are used in most programs which want to do files access.  I don't know why you would want to rename them as this is all the library would do but the only real alternative is to the use the command line tools.

Comment: Perhaps its might be time to reflect on why it might be that you have the highest number of unaccepted answers of anyone I have come across in SO.  Perhaps the world is not ready for your genius or perhaps you can change the way you approach problems.

Comment: @PL Plz look at the answers this q, how in the world is Guice even remotely an answer to my original q. I dont think you are being fair one bit. Would you honestly accept any of the answers to my unanswered questions ? Im pretty sure while you might accept some you would still have many unclosed ones just like me.

Comment: A few unacceptable answers is bad luck, having 100 unaccepted answers means either you are a mis-uderstood genius and the rest of the world is wrong, or it could be you are trying to tackle problems in ways no-one can understand.  My suggestion try to understand how things are normally done and try to ask questions which can be reasonably answered.

Comment: @PL Firstly its not fair and really bad form to attack the person, especially considering the simple fact you have never met me and the few words here dont tell much. Before you open your big mouth, go read my unanswered questions and the answers that follow then you will be better positioned to make some opinion.

Comment: @PL Maybe my questions are more in depth, but then again StackOverflow has enough brain dead questions that lets be fair are not interesting nor do they require any thought. Im sorry im not a newbie, i do not find it interesting to answer homework or complete newbit questions. If you cant handle or dont want to spend time on q that make you think then so be it, but dont go insulting random people.

Comment: @PL Yes i have lots of unaswered q, so how does that make me wrong. Is there anything wrong with asking questions ? Its too bad there arent more different questions instead of basic boring stuff that can be answered by a simple search.